# Optionally return either an array or a hash from a subroutine?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, subroutine

How can I return either a hash or an array from a subroutine, depending on what the user wants?

**Basically I want a subroutine that when asked to return a hash it will return a hash, but when asked to return an array it will return an array containing what would be the keys of that hash.**

ex:

```
my %hash = foo();

my @array = foo();  # @array contains "keys %hash"

# pseudo code
sub foo {

     # Define a hash
     my %hash = (
         'key1' => 'val1',
         'key2' => 'val2',
         'key3' => 'val3',
     );

     # I know this is not valid Perl code, but it represents what I want.
     return keys %hash if wantarray;
     return %hash      if wanthash;
}
```

I know you can use `wantarray` to determine whether you want an array or a scalar to be returned, but I need a similar functionality for optionally returning an array or a hash.

Comment: There's no such thing as 'array context' in Perl, I think: it's either _list_, scalar or void context. Why would you want such a functionality?

Comment: Perhaps [Want](http://search.cpan.org/~robin/Want-0.26/Want.pm) module will be of interest for you, however.

Comment: just always return \%hash and let the caller do `my @array = keys %{ foo() }` or `my %hash = %{ foo() }` (or better yet, just `my $hasherf = foo()`)

Comment: as @raina77ow says, wantarray is misnamed; it only tells you that there is list context

Comment: @ysth, I know I can get the keys from a function returning a hash by using `keys %{ foo() }`, I'm looking for a way to avoid just that.

Comment: By the way, is there someone just randomly going around downvoting Perl questions?  That '-1' was slapped on the instant I posted this question... I doubt whoever did it even had time to read it.

Comment: See also [`Contextual::Return`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Contextual::Return)

Comment: `Contextual::Return` looks interesting, but it looks like it only deals with ARRAYREF's or HASHREF's.  I'm looking for a solution that will return an array or a hash, not a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subroutine may return array or [reference to hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

```
my @array = foo();  # @array contains "keys %hash"
my $hash_reference = foo();

print $array[0],"\n"; # keys returned by foo are in random order
print $hash_reference->{key1},"\n";


# sample code
sub foo {

     # Define a hash
     my %hash = (
         'key1' => 'val1',
         'key2' => 'val2',
         'key3' => 'val3',
     );

     if( wantarray) {
         return keys %hash;
     }else{
         return \%hash
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a parameter so that if it's passed in, it returns keys:

```
sub foo {
    my $want_keys = shift;

    my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, );

    return keys %hash if $want_keys;

    return %hash;
}

my %hash = foo();

my @keys = foo(1); # or foo('keys');
```

The only other way to do this is a hash is returned if a list is wanted, otherwise an array reference of the keys, which means the caller will have to dereference afterwards:

```
sub foo {
    my %hash = (a=>1, b=>2);
    return %hash if wantarray;
    return [keys %hash];
}

my $keys = foo();
my %hash = foo();
```

Comment: That is a valid solution, but is also something I was trying to avoid.  I want the function to be called the same whether you want a hash or an array, and adjust the output accordingly.  I understand what I am asking may not be possible, but I figured I would ask before completely giving up on it.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the only other way I can think of to do this (return a hash if `wantarray`, otherwise return an aref with the keys)

Comment: Funny, that's the exact opposite of Andrzej's response :) Those both seem to be the best options.  I selected his since using wantarray to return an array makes more sense logically than it would to return a hash, but I gave your answer a +1 because it is also equally as valid.

Comment: I saw that right after I updated my answer :) It looked like you wanted to default to returning a hash, which is why I did it this way. Remember, as others have said, `wantarray` is not very aptly named. It should really be `wantlist` which both a hash and an array are.

Comment: I agree, but due to its unfortunate choice of name, it makes more sense to a user if `wantarray` returns an array :)

Comment: I feel like Perl should have a better way of differentiating between arrays and hashes though... Maybe in Perl 6?